# What is solution for error in vector in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

```
/*
// Sample code to perform I/O:

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int num;
    cin >> num;                                     // Reading input from STDIN
    cout << "Input number is " << num << endl;      // Writing output to STDOUT
}

// Warning: Printing unwanted or ill-formatted data to output will cause the test cases to fail
*/

// Write your code here
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include <algorithm>  
using namespace std;
typedef long long int ll;
vector<ll> v;
void make(ll num)
{
    if(num>10000000000)
        return ;
    if(num!=0)
        v.insert(num);
     make(num*10+4);
     make(num*10+7);
}
int main()
{
    ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(nullptr);

    ll num=0;
    make(num);
    ll n,ans=0;
    cin>>n;
    for(auto i:v)
    {
        for(auto j:v)
        {
            if(i<=n&&j<=n&&j>=i)
            {
                if(__gcd(i,j)==1)
                    ans++;
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<ans<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
In function 'void make(ll)':
30:21: error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<long long int>::insert(ll&)'


69:0,
20:
114:5: note: candidate: std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::insert(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::const_iterator, const value_type&) [with _Tp = long long int; _Alloc = std::allocator<long long int>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<long long int*, std::vector<long long int> >; typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer = long long int*; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::const_iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const long long int*, std::vector<long long int> >; typename __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Tp_alloc_type>::const_pointer = const long long int*; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = long long int]
:

114:5: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
64:0,
20:
1042:7: note: candidate: std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::insert(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::const_iterator, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type&&) [with _Tp = long long int; _Alloc = std::allocator<long long int>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<long long int*, std::vector<long long int> >; typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer = long long int*; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::const_iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const long long int*, std::vector<long long int> >; typename __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Tp_alloc_type>::const_pointer = const long long int*; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = long long int]


1042:7: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
1059:7: note: candidate: std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::insert(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::const_iterator, std::initializer_list<_Tp>) [with _Tp = long long int; _Alloc = std::allocator<long long int>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<long long int*, std::vector<long long int> >; typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer = long long int*; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::const_iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const long long int*, std::vector<long long int> >; typename __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Tp_alloc_type>::const_pointer = const long long int*]


1059:7: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
1084:7: note: candidate: std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::insert(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::const_iterator, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type, const value_type&) [with _Tp = long long int; _Alloc = std::allocator<long long int>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<long long int*, std::vector<long long int> >; typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer = long long int*; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::const_iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const long long int*, std::vector<long long int> >; typename __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Tp_alloc_type>::const_pointer = const long long int*; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = long long int]


1084:7: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 1 provided
1128:2: note: candidate: template<class _InputIterator, class> std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::insert(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::const_iterator, _InputIterator, _InputIterator) [with _InputIterator = _InputIterator; <template-parameter-2-2> = <template-parameter-1-2>; _Tp = long long int; _Alloc = std::allocator<long long int>]


1128:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
30:21: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 1 provided<br>
```

How to solve the problem

Comment: the function `iterator insert( iterator pos, const T& value );` takes in an iterator and the value

Comment: There is no function called insert in vector. What is __gcd? Is it a user-defined function created by you?

Comment: I don't understand what u mention

Comment: Have a look at the documentation for [`std::vector::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert).

Comment: @Sumeet __gcd is under algorithm  library

Comment: @Sumeet, **G.M.**'s comment contains a link that proves you wrong.

Comment: insert function uses iterator while in your case you are directly using value, where is iterator in your case?

Comment: `typedef long long int ll;` -- I see this crazy macro too often.  Why not simply use `int64_t` instead of this?  It is more descriptive of *exactly* the type of integer you want to use, and isn't something that looks like the number `11`.

Comment: Re. `"__gcd is under algorithm library"`, note that `__gcd` is a reserved identifier and almost certainly not meant for public consumption.  The `algorithm` library actually has [`std::gcd`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/gcd).

Comment: @G.M. ya that's correct

Answer (score 7):

In function make(), try using `v.push_back(num)` instead of `v.insert(num)` it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You lack the first parameter in your `vector::insert`, the position the new element should be placed after.
If you don't want to use `vector::push_back` as suggested in the previous answer, here is a MWE:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

typedef long long int ll;
vector<ll> v;

void make(ll num)
{
    if(num>10000000000)
        return;
    if(num!=0)
        v.insert(v.begin(),num);   // iterator to insert position added
    make(num*10+4);
    make(num*10+7);
}

int main()
{
    ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(nullptr);

    ll num=0;
    make(num);
    ll n,ans=0;
    cout << "Input number: " << endl;
    cin>>n;
    for(auto i:v)
    {
        for(auto j:v)
        {
            if(i<=n&&j<=n&&j>=i)
            {
                if(__gcd(i,j)==1)
                    ans++;
            }
        }
    }

    cout<< "answer = " << ans <<endl;

return 0;
}
```

What is this for? A random number generator?

Comment: find coprime where two number consist of only '4' and '7'